# What is the safest way to pigtail aluminum wiring?

Tags: electrical, wiring, aluminum-wiring

I'm looking for a way to remediate the aluminum wiring in a home built in the 1970s.  Currently, the whole house is wired with aluminum and the switches/outlets are original and not aluminum rated.

After looking around online, I've seen three popular ways of dealing with this situation (besides rewiring the house):

1. Pigtail the fixtures/switches/receptacles with copper wire using [AlumiConn](https://www.google.com/search?q=alumiconn) connectors.
2. Pigtail the fixtures/switches/receptacles with copper wire using aluminum-rated wire nuts (purple).
3. Replace the existing switches and receptacles with aluminum-rated ones ("CO/ALR") and use solution 1 or 2 for everything that isn't a switch or a receptacle.

Everyone seems to have various opinions on which is the best way to do it.  Most of the electricians I've talked to so far have claimed that #2 is the best way to do it, but without having a good reason why (other than "that's the way we typically do it").

Which is the best option, and why?  Is it possible to mix those methods?

Comment: Think it comes down to a cost/benefit/labour.  #2 is probably least cost and easy and does the same as #1 and #3.

Comment: All 3 methods are considered safe and use UL approved methods. How do you define "safest"?

Comment: The "best way to do it" is to use the method approved by your local code officer.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for using **method #2** the rated wing nut is:

- lower cost
- time and speed
- use less space

Con

- limited capacity (can't join multiple wires)
- nut can only be used once
- the twist can weaken the alu wire and retwisting will most likely break the end of the wire off and shorten the wire.

**Method 1 - using the alumiConn**

- only choice if the Alu wire is short
- easy to make a tight connection
- handle multiple size wire and multiple wires (buy the size and ports needed)

Con

- Takes up a lot space (in a tight box, difficult to fit them in
- expensive and for larger size wire - multiple ports - Really Expensive

Yes - you can mix the three methods to fix any of the outlets that do not have aluminum-rated receptacles.

It would unusual to have none rated alu outlets and switches in a house wired with ALU wire unless the owner/tenents did replacements with improper receptacles.

If you are not pigtailing copper wire, then you need to replace the existing switches and receptacles with aluminum-rated ones ("CO/ALR").

For the outlets and switches you have pigtailed copper wire, then regular copper-rated receptacles can be used.

As others have recommended, always use the screw terminals and not the jab in the back.  Alu wire always have to screwed on.

Comment: I use AlumiConns on the hot and neutral and a wire nut with antioxidant paste (Burndy Penetrox) on the ground.